# Ожидание ввода пользователя Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio

Существуют ли функции поточных вводов и выводов, как cin в с++,в Rstudio?

И как пользователь будет работать с данными и пакетами, в терминале, где этот пакет описывался, или в консоле?

Comment: `?scan`,  `?readline`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Полезная ссылка - https://www.datamentor.io/r-programming/examples/user-input/

```r
my.name <- readline(prompt="Enter name: ")
my.age <- readline(prompt="Enter age: ")
```

Работает пользователь через терминал.